# Configuring wps service in the lizmap web client

Tags: wps, lizmap

I can run lizmap web client after configuring the lizmap web client according to [Updated - Installing Apache, QGIS Server, And Lizmap Web Client On Windows OS](https://opengislab.com/blog/2018/7/7/updated-installing-apache-qgis-server-and-lizmap-on-windows-os).  There is a way ([Lizmap WPS Web Client](https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-wps-web-client-module)) to configure it. But I don't know how to configure wps in the lizmap client. Can you give a specific example: including wps_url, wps_rootDirectories, redis_port and ows_url. I am a beginner about how to configure wms, wps service. And what is role of the qgis-wps4server?

```
[wps]
wps_url=http://wps:8080
wps_rootDirectories=/projects/wps
redis_host=localhost
redis_port=6379
redis_key_prefix=lzmwps
ows_url=http://map:8080
```

Comment: I have the same question, working on Debian 12. Any progress in the past 5 years? :D